# Access object value in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, object

I would like to access the date value from this object in WordPress,
but I can't get any results.

```
 $dates = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) FROM wp_posts 
                              ORDER BY post_date");
     foreach($dates as $date){
             echo $date->YEAR(post_date);
            }



 stdClass Object
    (
        [YEAR(post_date)] => 2010
    )
    stdClass Object
    (
        [YEAR(post_date)] => 2011
    )
    stdClass Object
    (
        [YEAR(post_date)] => 2012
    )
    stdClass Object
    (
        [YEAR(post_date)] => 2013
    )
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name of "YEAR(post_date)", try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) as pDate FROM wp_posts ORDER BY post_date
```

You can call with: `$date->pDate;`

*Note: I added `as pDate` to the query*

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
print_r($date->{'YEAR(post_date)'});
```

or simply change the name in the query